# Laravel - get last time a table was updated

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am interested in getting the last time a table was updated (which is **not necessarily** the newest entry - entries might be deleted as well).

In SQL, the solution is easy:

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDb' AND TABLE_NAME = 'myTable';
```

However, the only way I manage to do so is to create a new connection.
Assume that my connection is called `mysqlConn`, my new conenction will look like:

```
'mysqlConnScheme' => [
    'driver'      => *** same as mysqlConn ***,
    'host'        => *          - " -        *, 
    'port'        => *          - " -        *, 
    'username'    => *          - " -        *, 
    'password'    => *          - " -        *, 
    'database'    => 'information_schema',
],
```

Then I can retrieve it by:

```
$updateTime = DB::connection('mysqlConnScheme')
    ->setDatabaseName('information_schema')
    ->table('tables')
    ->select('UPDATE_TIME')
    ->where('TABLE_SCHEMA', '=', 'myDb')
    ->where('TABLE_NAME', '=', 'myTable')
    ->first();
```

I wonder if there is any way to do so without creating another connection.

Comment: I have used a datetime field that I always set to `NOW()` on `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s, but that would be interesting if there was a more native method.

Comment: If each of your tables has a model associated with it, and you used `$table->timestamps()` in the migration, then each table should have an `updated_at` column that is automatically updated whenever a row is changed. If you scroll down a bit here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions you can see the Timestamps section and how it works

Comment: To add to @TimLewis: To include deleted entries you'll also have to use [soft delete](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is, as I mentioned, deleted entries. I didn't know about soft delete, it is very interesting but in my case hard delete is necessary.